# Calendar HOUR_OF_DAY return 0 when parsing 12:00

Tags: java, calendar

I was surprised why the Calendar `HOUR_OF_DAY` prints 0 in the example below, when I parse 2014-10-06 12:00:00.

I understand if HOUR print 0, but should not HOUR_OF_DAY print 12?

```
  String dateString = "2014-10-06 12:00:00";

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

  try
  {
     cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateString));
  }catch(Exception e)
  {}

  System.out.print(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)); // Print 0 ???????
```

Comment: why? It is doing what it says it should. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY

Comment: set your rtime to a 24H clock

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use uppercase `H` in your pattern

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Because:

```
h is Hour in am/pm (1-12) 
H Hour in day (0-23)
```

For more information see [the documentation of SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: yes of course, I forgot it. It's a bit misleading that 2014-10-06 13:00:00 works as it should. Thank you!